# how to use Dtrace to check malloc on Solaris 10?

Tags: c, solaris, dtrace

I meet a troublesome bug about memory usage, so I want to use Dtrace to check malloc and free on Solaris 10.

I use the following command

```
dtrace -l | grep malloc
```

The output is:

```
7000        fbt              unix                       prom_malloc entry
7001        fbt              unix                       prom_malloc return
7141        fbt           genunix                       cacl_malloc entry
7142        fbt           genunix                       cacl_malloc return
12319        fbt           genunix                   rmallocmap_wait entry
12320        fbt           genunix                   rmallocmap_wait return
13078        fbt           genunix                      rmalloc_wait entry
13079        fbt           genunix                      rmalloc_wait return
13526        fbt           genunix                        rmallocmap entry
13527        fbt           genunix                        rmallocmap return
16846        fbt           genunix                           rmalloc entry
16847        fbt           genunix                           rmalloc return
25931        fbt             tmpfs                      tmp_memalloc entry
25932        fbt             tmpfs                      tmp_memalloc return
```

It seems there is no malloc.

I have checked Solaris Internal, and found the malloc calls sbrk. So I use the following command:

```
dtrace -l | grep sbrk
```

But there is nothing found.

So how can I use Dtrace to check malloc on Solaris 10?

Comment: I guess this tool will be useful for you:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/11/finding-memory-leaks-on-solaris-is-no.html

Comment: @Vijay: Thanks very much for your comments, and it is a very cool tool!

Comment: @Vijay: Are you willing to open your tool's source code?

Comment: drop me a mail bvsarathi@gmail.com or comment on the blog with your email

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various tools that already implement the logic required to identify memory leaks under Solaris,

- libumem & mdb (`UMEM_DEBUG=default UMEM_LOGGING=transaction LD_PRELOAD=libumem.so.1` then `mdb's ::findleaks`)
- dbx (`check -leaks`)

Should you still want to go the `dtrace` way, you need to trace the process you suspect to leak memory using the pid provider. You searched the kernel probes with `dtrace -l` and found nothing but this is expected as the kernel does not implement `malloc` or `brk`. They are userland functions located in the C standard library.

This script will trace every `malloc` and `free` calls by a program:

```
dtrace -qn '
pid$target:libc:malloc:entry {
        self->size=arg0;
}
pid$target:libc:malloc:return /self->size/ {
        printf("malloc(%d)=%p\n",self->size,arg1);
        self->size=0;
}
pid$target:libc:free:entry {
        printf("free(%p)\n",arg0);
}
' -c program_to_trace
```

For more in-depth examples, have a look to http://ewaldertl.blogspot.fr/2010/09/debugging-memory-leaks-with-dtrace-and.html and http://www.joyent.com/blog/bruning-questions-debugging

Comment: Would you mind explaining why the return pointer is in arg1 instead of arg0? I'm pretty green at dtrace but for something like `syscall::open:return`, the file descriptor is in arg0

Comment: @genghiskhan That's by design. I'm using the pid provider which has a different behavior than the syscall provider you are referring to. With the pid provider [A return probe fires when the traced function returns or makes a tail call to another function. The value for arg0 is the offset in the function of the return instruction; arg1 holds the return value.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E53395/gkycz.html#OSDTGgkyfx). Note that with the syscall provider, the return value is both in arg0 and arg1.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the great explanation.

Answer (score -1):

For example, in order to trace all malloc calls with dtrace, by printing each allocation you would write (to a file named trace-malloc.d in this example) a script like below:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

    pid$1::malloc:entry
    {
        self->trace = 1;
        self->size = arg0;
    }

    pid$1::malloc:return
    /self->trace == 1/
    {
        /* log the memory allocation */
        printf("<__%i;%Y;%d;malloc;0x%x;%d;\n", i++, walltimestamp, tid, arg1, self->size);
        ustack(50);
        printf("__>\n\n");

        self->trace = 0;
        self->size = 0;
    }
```

and then call it by passing the process id of the process you want to trace,
for example:

```
./trace-malloc.d 12345
```

In complex programs there are very frequent memory allocations and de-allocations so I've written a small program to help me identify memory leaks with dtrace. Each memory operation with malloc / calloc / realloc and free is traced and then an analysis program reads and processes all the traces and points out suspected memory leaks, also using various heuristics to point out strongly suspected memory leaks. If you are interested you can check it out here:

https://github.com/ppissias/DTLeakAnalyzer.

Comment: Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code/process on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See:  [What signifies “Good” self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212)

Comment: @Shree The post starts with "I've written". So, isn't that a clear statement who wrote the tool?

Comment: @AdrianW I always imagine answer without link.If with out link it's address a question and link is for only reference I am not flagged the answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback of the reply, I have changed it accordingly to also include an answer to the question. The intention was to help someone else who has the same problem, as I was also searching for available tools using dtrace not too long ago.